# How can i make 3 labels to display counting numbers out of overall?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In form1 designer:

[image: Out of]

In label1 the counting numbers out of numbers in label25.
In the middle i added another label just for the "/"

but the result when i'm running the program is that there is a big space/s between the labels: I tried to move the "/" and label25 as much as i can to the left close to label1 but it's not a good way to do it.

What is the best way to achieve it ?

[image: out of when program is running]

In form1 i have this class:

```
public class MyProgress
        {
            public string Report1 { get; set; }
            public string Report2 { get; set; }
            public string Report3 { get; set; }
            public string Report4 { get; set; }
        }
```

Then the method DirSearch where i also making report progress of backgroundworker1:

```
int numberofdirs = 0;
        void DirSearch(string rootDirectory, string filesExtension, string[] textToSearch, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> resultsoftextfound = new List<string>();
            List<string> resultsoftextfound1 = new List<string>();
            List<string> filePathList = new List<string>();
            int numberoffiles = 0;
            try
            {
                filePathList = SearchAccessibleFilesNoDistinct(rootDirectory, null,worker,e).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                string ad = err.ToString();
            }
            label21.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        label21.Text = "Phase 2: Searching in files";
                    });
            MyProgress myp = new MyProgress();
            myp.Report4 = filePathList.Count.ToString();
            foreach (string file in filePathList)
            {
                try
                {
                    _busy.WaitOne();
                    if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        return;
                    }

                    bool reportedFile = false;

                    for (int i = 0; i < textToSearch.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (File.ReadAllText(file).IndexOf(textToSearch[i], StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                        {
                            resultsoftextfound.Add(file + "  " + textToSearch[i]);
                            if (!reportedFile)
                            {
                                numberoffiles++;

                                myp.Report1 = file;
                                myp.Report2 = numberoffiles.ToString();
                                myp.Report3 = textToSearch[i];
                                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, myp);
                                reportedFile = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    numberofdirs++;
                    label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        label1.Text = numberofdirs.ToString();
                        label1.Visible = true;
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

In this line i report the overall files count:

```
myp.Report4 = filePathList.Count.ToString();
```

Then later reporting the number of files count:

```
myp.Report2 = numberoffiles.ToString();
```

And updating label1:

```
label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        label1.Text = numberofdirs.ToString();
                        label1.Visible = true;
                    });
```

This is the backgorundworker1 dowork event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            _stopwatch.Restart();
            string[] values = textBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { ",," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            DirSearch(textBox3.Text, textBox2.Text, values, worker, e);
            _stopwatch.Stop();
        }
```

And the progresschanged event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyProgress mypro = (MyProgress)e.UserState;
            ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(mypro.Report1);
            label15.Text = mypro.Report2;
            label25.Text = mypro.Report4;
            label15.Visible = true;
            if (ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Count > 9)
                textBox4.Enabled = true;
        }
```

In the end what i want to do when running the program is to display the count of files out of overall files for example: 21 / 244 where 21 is the counter.

Comment: Why don't you use just one label and format correctly the text for this single lable with the two values and the slash? Please show your actual code that sets these labels

Comment: Please take more care when formatting your code. *Every* code snippet is massively indented after the first line, presumably because you originally copied and pasted from the start of the *text* in the first line. Use the post preview to make sure that the code looks as readable as you can make it.

Comment: _label15.Text = string.Format("{0}/{1}", mypro.Report2,mypro.Report4);_ just make the label long enough and remove the unnecessary labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use three different labels take the following steps:

- Add on your form "FlowLayoutPanel"
- Change it "Auto-Size" property to "True"
- Put your labels on it
- Go to the properties of each label and set "Margin" to "0; 6; 0; 0",
  "0; 3; 0; 0" and "0; 0; 0; 0".

[It would look like so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4seL.gif)

P.S. I would suggest you to use only one label and put it there as formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the text alignment in the label controls.  Align the leftmost label to the right and the rightmost label to the left.  Align the "/" character label to "center" and make it very narrow.  Then adjust all to have the same text baseline with the horizontal alignment tool.